# Optimizing computation on a sliding window for large DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rolling-computation

I need to optimize sliding window computations for a large DataFrame (time series of 10000x10000). The current implementation is slow.

I have a DataFrame, and I want to perform myFunc for each line of my df, on the 255 last non-zero lines.

```
            df = self.df
            df = df.replace(0, np.nan)
            df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
            result = df.rolling(window=255).apply(myFunc, raw=True)
            res = pd.DataFrame(index=self.df.index, columns=self.df.columns)
            res.update(result)
            return res[(res != 0).any(axis=1)]
```

I tried to replicate the process using NumPy, but the performance is quite similar.

```
            df_np = self.df.to_numpy()
            result = np.zeros_like(df_np)
            window_size = 255
            indices = np.where(~np.all(df_np == 0, axis=1))
            for i in indices[0]:
                if i >= window_size:
                    valid_indices = indices[0][np.where(indices[0] <= i)[0]][-window_size:]
                    if len(valid_indices) >= window_size:
                        result[i] = np.apply_along_axis(myFunc, 0, df_np[valid_indices, :])
            res = pd.DataFrame(result, index=self.df.index, columns=self.df.columns)
            return res[(res != 0).any(axis=1)]
```

Is there a way to improve it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try dask for parallel execution you code over pandas

```
pip install dask
```

you can create dask dataframe from your existing pandas dataframe

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)

window_size = 255
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(lambda partition: partition.rolling(window=window_size).apply(myFunc), meta=('float64'))

result_df = ddf.compute()
```

I think you should search solution in paralleling your code execution rather search optimisation solution, because I think you get reach somehow the limit

Answer (score 0):

You can easily parallelize your pandas calculations using [parallel-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-pandas/) library. You won't even need to change your code (well, almost)
For your example:

```py
import time

import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
#pip install parallel-pandas
from parallel_pandas import ParallelPandas
import numpy as np
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# you can specify numbers of cpu cores here and turn-on/of progress bar
ParallelPandas.initialize()

# your awesome function
def foo(arr):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(arr))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create big DataFrame as you need
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10000, 10000)))
    
    # create dask dataframe 
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=16)
    
    # start default pandas rolling 
    start = time.perf_counter()
    res1 = df.rolling(255).apply(foo, raw=True)
    print(f'synchronous time took {time.perf_counter() - start}')
    
    # start dask parallel rolling
    start = time.perf_counter()
    res2 = ddf.rolling(255).apply(foo, raw=True).compute(scheduler='processes')
    print(f'dask parallel time took {time.perf_counter() - start}')
    
    # p_apply - is parallel variant of apply method
    start = time.perf_counter()
    res3 = df.rolling(255).p_apply(foo, raw=True)
    print(f'parallel-pandas time took {time.perf_counter() - start}')
    
    # chek if equals our results
    if res1.equals(res2):
        print('synchronous and dask parallel are equal')
    if res1.equals(res3):
        print('synchronous and parallel-pandas are equal')
```

Out:

```
synchronous time took 162.48357940800088
dask parallel time took 72.19614506300059
APPLY DONE: 100%|██████████| 32/32 [00:17<00:00,  1.80it/s]
parallel-pandas time took 17.903414761000022
synchronous and dask parallel are equal
synchronous and parallel-pandas are equal
```

So, we have almost 10X speedup!

**As a bonus!!!**

if you  install [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) library, you can do it several times faster

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10000, 10000)))
 
    start = time.perf_counter()
    res1 = df.rolling(255).apply(foo, raw=True, engine='numba', engine_kwargs={'nopython': True, 'parallel': True})
    print(f'numba time took {time.perf_counter() - start}')
    start = time.perf_counter()
    res3 = df.rolling(255).p_apply(foo, raw=True, engine='numba', engine_kwargs={'nopython': True})
    print(f'parallel-pandas with numba time took {time.perf_counter() - start}')
```

Out:

```
numba time took 4.115762158999132
APPLY DONE: 100%|██████████| 32/32 [00:03<00:00, 10.07it/s]
parallel-pandas time took 3.4635137490004126
```

Thus, the final acceleration is almost 40 times! Cool isn't it?

And Dask won’t help here, it’s needed for a few other tasks.